# Determinar todos los múltiplos de un número en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Empiezo en la programación con Python hace solo unos días y pues quiero desarrollar un programa para un problema sencillo. Básicamente debo leer un número de tres dígitos y determinar qué dígitos son múltiplos de otros dígitos, actualmente tengo desarrollado ya un programa y realiza todo como se le ordena, pero solo puede mostrar si uno de los dígitos es múltiplo de otro, pero no todos los dígitos múltiplos de otros.
Así, por ejemplo, si ingreso el 248 según el código me dirá que el 8 es múltiplo de 4 y finalizará, pero el 8 también es múltiplo de 2 y esto no lo imprimirá. ¿Hay algún modo de poder imprimir todos los posibles múltiplos que los dígitos puedan tener?
Otra cosa es que en el ejercicio no se me permite usar estructuras de ciclos o listas, si se puede realizar sin utilizar estas estructuras estaría agradecido, pero igual no hay problema si es necesario utilizarlas.

```html
from math import log10
from math import ceil
Num=abs(int(input('Digite un número entero de tres dígitos')))
if Num==0 or Num==1:
    print('El número ingresado no tiene tres dígitos \a')
else:
    Num_Dig=ceil(log10(Num))
    if Num_Dig!=3:  
        print('El número ingresado no tiene tres dígitos \a')
    else:
        Dig_1=Num%10
        Dig_2=(Num%100)//10
        Dig_3=(Num//100)
        if Dig_1%Dig_2==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_1} es multiplo de {Dig_2}')
        elif Dig_1%Dig_3==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_1} es multiplo de {Dig_3}')
        elif Dig_2%Dig_1==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_2} es multiplo de {Dig_1}')
        elif Dig_2%Dig_3==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_2} es multiplo de {Dig_3}')
        elif Dig_3%Dig_1==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_3} es multiplo de {Dig_1}')
        else:
            print(f'Ningún dígito en el número {Num} es multiplo de otro')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema en la lógica de tu código, ya que estas realizando comprobaciones excluyentes,es decir, al utiliza `elif` si alguna de las comprobaciones es cierta no realizará las demás. Lo que debes hacer es realizar todas las comprobaciones una tras otra ya que no puedes usar bucles ni listas.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```
from math import log10
from math import ceil
Num=abs(int(input('Digite un número entero de tres dígitos')))
if Num==0 or Num==1:
    print('El número ingresado no tiene tres dígitos \a')
else:
    Num_Dig=ceil(log10(Num))
    if Num_Dig!=3:  
        print('El número ingresado no tiene tres dígitos \a')
    else:
        Dig_1=Num%10
        Dig_2=(Num%100)//10
        Dig_3=(Num//100)
        ninguno = True
        if Dig_1%Dig_2==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_1} es multiplo de {Dig_2}')
            ninguno = False
        if Dig_1%Dig_3==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_1} es multiplo de {Dig_3}')
            ninguno = False
        if Dig_2%Dig_1==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_2} es multiplo de {Dig_1}')
            ninguno = False
        if Dig_2%Dig_3==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_2} es multiplo de {Dig_3}')
            ninguno = False
        if Dig_3%Dig_1==0:
            print(f'El dígito {Dig_3} es multiplo de {Dig_1}')
            ninguno = False
        if ninguno:
            print(f'Ningún dígito en el número {Num} es multiplo de otro')
```

Espero que te sirva, cualquier duda pregunta en los comentarios.

Un saludo